# General Questions about Stacktracing jquery errors

Tags: jquery, exception, stack-trace

I am certain that there is a topic about this already, however, I do not know how to search for this.

Usually, stacktraces in JS are pretty straightforward. The throw an error, and in the console you can see the line where the error happend.

But sometimes you will run into something like this:
[image]

As you can see, there is nothing which helps you except the very first line. Is there a good way to debug this kind of errors?

Looking deeper into this error will only give me more lines of code from angular.js or jquery.min.js

Comment: What I'd do in this situation it figure out what event is causing the error, then set a `debugger` and step through it. Normally this issue is caused by your code passing in arguments to jQuery methods that aren't in the correct state or type.

Comment: You will get better stack traces if you use `jquery.js` instead of `jquery.min.js`.